# QueryException in Connection.php line 770 in laravel

Tags: laravel

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin.product__images' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `product__images` (`image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (uecJylfFeDlTCKQI96Ipgd2F8kBWWd.jpeg, 2018-07-18 06:06:45, 2018-07-18 06:06:45))

Comment: What if you run this query directly in your database, do you get the same error?

Comment: Did you include your table name in the model file like public $table = "product_images";

Comment: Is the error being thrown when you're using a model or are you just using the query builder (`DB`)? Please can you add the code that is causing the error and if you are using a model can you also add the code from that to your question.

Comment: Please update your question with product__images migration.

Comment: yes,table name in the model file like public $table = "product_images";

Comment: Add protected $table = 'product_images'; In model as I seen that you have 2 underscore sign in the name

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin.product__images' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `product__images` where `product_id` = [])

Comment: $id=new product_image;
        //$id->product_id=$product->id;
        $image=new Product_Image(array(
            Product_Image::where('product_id',$id)->with('Product')->get(),
            'image'=>$picName,
        ));

Comment: Add the model and controller code in the question

Comment: have you run php artisan migrate? run this command php artisan migrate if you haven't  and if you have already run this command then post your migration code

Comment: my model and migration does not match

Answer (score 0):

```
   $product = new Product(array(
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'price' => $request->get('price'),
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
            'shipping' => $request->get('shipping'),
        ));
    $product->save();
    $id=$product->id;


    $data=new Productimage(array(
        'product_id'=>$id,
        'image'=>$picName,
    ));
```